# timing an operation in java

Tags: java, eclipse, timing

I want to run my program in eclipse but I want to see how long it takes to run the program. In other words I want to time my program. I know that in UNIX I can time any operation by placing the word “time” before the command on the command line. But I dont know how I might be able to time my operation in Eclipse. Just to make everything a bit more clear, I want to avoid writing new methods. Is there a way that I could add sth to my configuration path? Does anyone have an idea of how I can do so?

Comment: Do you really need to run on eclipse? Why not run it with terminal?

Comment: I have windows machine, Can I do so? if I can run it on terminal on windows, Could you please kindly guide me how I can do so?

Comment: You can use something like this http://visualvm.java.net/ but you might end up getting lot more info then you nee

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind adding two lines of code, you can do this purely in Java:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long ms = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // do whatever

        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - ms);
    }
}
```

You could also use [`nanoTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) if you need it.

Comment: @BBB You should use a shutdownhook to guarantee you get results.

Comment: @ChuckFricano You don't need a shutdown hook for this. You are guaranteed that both lines of code will run. Also, if this answer worked for you, BBB, you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: @Jeffrey What about an exception in //doWhatever?

Comment: @ChuckFricano Why would you ever want to time a broken application?

Comment: @Jeffrey Also, How about an extra return or System.exit(42); or a JFrame's EXIT_ON_CLOSE  - you need the shutdown hook.

Comment: @ChuckFricano In those situations a shutdown hook would be needed since the OP is against refactoring his code. However, it should be noted that shutdown hooks are started in an unspecified order and that may affect the time you receive.

Comment: @Jeffrey In those situations, without the shutdown hook, you receive no results.  Your argument that shutdown hooks are started in an unspecified order is meaningless.  Result will be skewed by milliseconds if not nanoseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Add a system.out.println at the end of your app to indicate how long it ran.

Answer (score 0):

Put this class somewhere in your code:

```
package your.package.name.common;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class CProfile {
    /**
     * Logger for this class
     */
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CProfile.class);

    public static final int SECONDS_TO_ALERT = 2;

    public static void slownessAlert(long startTime, String name) {
        long seconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(System.nanoTime() - startTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        if (seconds>SECONDS_TO_ALERT){
            logger.warn("slow method detected: "+name+" "+seconds+"s");
        }
    }

}
```

Then use this snippet in your code in following way:

```
public void something() {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    //SOME HEAVY COMPUTATIONS

    CProfile.slownessAlert(startTime, "something");
}
```

It will inform you about slowness when it happens (SECONDS_TO_ALERT>2s).

Answer (score 0):

Add the speed-tracer plugin to eclipse if it is a web application.It will help u find out the time for everything.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this and guarantee you will get results is to add the following to the top of your main class.  This code will save the app start time and then add JVM shutdown hook that will fire and print the duration when the JVM shutsdown.

```
final static long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
static {
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("My program ran for "+( System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime )+" seconds.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
}
```